# CentOS - Cron job beginner

Tags: linux, cron, centos

I'm trying to set a Cron job that will start every day for backup purpose.

I have copied an existing job I saw inside /etc/cron.daily and just edited the file with vim
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6edx93pvn7ukiqo/terminal1.png?dl=0

Here is my the backup Cron file I want to execute (just run 2 lines of command, should be root):

```
  sudo /usr/bin/s3cmd put /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb s3://forumupload/
  sudo /usr/bin/s3cmd put -r /home/maximur1/nodebb/public/uploads s3://forumupload
```

Both commands run when I run them on the command line, but in the Cron file, they don't get executed each day like they should. Anything I'm missing?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0txc03p4wgc4xub/cronjob.png?dl=0

Comment: The links are to screenshots of an `ls` command and a couple of `s3cmd` commands. If you're asking about crontab entries, please include the crontab entries themselves *as text* in your question.

Comment: Just to clarify, the first screenshot show the file "backupforum" that I added in "etc/cron.daily", and the content of this file is in the screenshot #2

Comment: Screenshots are far less useful than plain text included in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks guy, I added the two line of code i'm trying to run in a Cron job.  The method I used was not sucessfull (adding a plain file inside /etc/cron.daily with theses 2 line of code.

Comment: I would log in as root and use 'crontab -e' to add backup jobs and 'crontab -l' to list them.

Comment: @GoinOff, I didn't know crontab -e let you edit the current crontab list of job. I added my two job at the end in there, I will see if it works tonight! 
[...]
0 2 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/bin/backup
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/s3cmd put /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb s3://forumupload/
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/s3cmd put -r /home/maximur1/nodebb/public/uploads s3://forumupload

Comment: It should work fine.  crontab is the way to go when using CentOS and Redhat.  Any user can setup their own cron job using this utility.

Comment: Thanks it worked last night! added these 2 jobs at 3AM and I have the files on my S3.  Not sure how to mark your comment as answer

Comment: I'll add an answer and you can mark it.  Glad I could help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a backup, I would log in as root and use `crontab -e` to add backup jobs and `crontab -l` to list them.  Any user can setup their own cron job using this utility on CentOS or Redhat system. Look at `man crontab` for more information.